# Adding additional SSD vs cloning and replacing existing SSD speed/performance

Tags: ssd, performance, samsung-ssd

I want to upgrade my laptop (Dell G3 Gaming Laptop) hard drive.

It came with a 512 GB SSD which is currently installed
I just bought the 970 Evo Plus 2 TB which is considerably faster

The motherboard has slots for two SSDs, so I could either:

A) Keep my existing 512 GB installed and ADD the 2 TB drive and install the games on the 2 TB HD, OR

B) Clone my 512 GB to my new 2 TB drive and then swap them out, OR

I want the fastest load time.

My guess is that if I did A, my boot load times would remain the same (since the OS is installed on the 512 GB SSD, but since the games are installed on the 2 TB hard drive, the games would load faster

Vs doing B, which would speed up both the OS loading time as well as the game loading time since everything is now on the 2 TB (much faster) SSD.

Am I right?

Or would doing either give me the same gaming performance (remember games are installed on the 2 TB SSD in either case).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend option B.

If you do A, you'd probably notice some difference but only when opening apps stored on the Evo, depending on how much faster the Evo drive is. This is because you'd still have to wait for all the OS stuff to load before you get to your games.

For Option B: I would use Clonezilla to clone the existing 512GB drive's data on to the 2TB drive. You could keep the 512GB drive as a backup for a while and then possibly turn it in to a dedicated swap drive. A dedicated swap drive won't really give you any benefit if you have plenty of RAM.

Another option, that I do not recommend, is to use both SSDs to create a Striped Software RAID Volume. This can generally get you greater speeds, but I don't like this approach because it's a lot riskier for data corruption. Also, if the 512GB drive is a lot slower, then this would in fact slow you down. If you try this, I strongly strongly recommend you come up with a reliable full backup solution.

You can download Clonezilla from here:
https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php

You may also like to use a benchmark tool to check how fast each drive can read/write data, here's one tool for that:
http://www.hdtune.com/